# css targeting specific paragraph with no class or id

Tags: html, css-selectors

I'am trying to target the paragraph with cssSelectors to get the value of "2%" that is in paragraph tag.

here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="row text">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Number Eligible Voters</h3>
            <p>5,656,705</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Electoral Threshold</h3>
            <p>2%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Total Votes</h3>
            <p>3,833,646</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Total Votes</h3>
            <p>3,792,742</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried `section .text .col-md-8:nth-child(1) p` but no success

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Assuming this .row.text is inside a <section>, and this is not a CSS styling question but a Selenium or other web testing/scraping question, that selector will match <p>5,656,705</p> before matching <p>2%</p>. Try `section .text .col-md-8:nth-child(1) .row:nth-child(1) .col-sm-6:nth-child(2) p`